# JavaScript to Active Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing around with Twitter Bootstrap's [Tooltips](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), but am having problems since they moved away from Twipsy. The correect JavaScript is included in the page.

Let's say I have the following:

```
<p><a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="hello">hover on me</a></p>
```

What is the *exact* JavaScript I need to use to make the tooltip appear?

Thanks in advance!

- Vanessa

Answer (score 39):

You need to explicitly run `.tooltip()` for all elements that have to have tooltip. For example, this will work:

```
<span rel="tooltip" title="tooltip text">some text</span>
...
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd rather go with this solution as it won't impact all other links. 
I'm just not sure the offset is a valid option for tooltip, it's not mentioned in the doc and doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: How would I accomplish if I wanted to run this for anything that's defer loaded by JavaScript, by using jquery.on()?

Comment: I think you should use jQuery.live()

Answer (score 15):

For your example it will just be:

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

but according to the documentation, you should use the `title` attribute, not `data-original-title`. That attribute is added by Bootstrap's tooltip code. Also there is no need for `rel="tooltip"`.

Your code should be:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="hello">hover on me</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a").tooltip(); // this will trigger a tooltip on all <a> elements
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, We need to manually initialize Tooltips

its mentioned in their Documentation also.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need exactly to

```
  <script src="bootstrap-tooltip.js "></script>
  <script>
    $(function (){
$('a').tooltip();
 });
```