# Bootstrap tooltip without a link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

To save space in a narrow table cell I want to use the bootstrap tooltip to display extra content on hover.  However, the tooltip uses the :rel option in the a tag.  I do not need a link, just its options...and I don't want the link to go anywhere.  I have used:

```
  link_to display.text, "#", :rel => "tooltip", ...blah..blah
  link_to_function display.text, "#", :rel => ...blah...blah
```

Both work to an extent, however both return to the top of the page.

Its probably smelly code to use a link that isn't really a link to get at some other function.  Is there a rails way of creating a dummy link?  Is there an "approved" method of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can initialize tooltips on other elements besides anchors. Try a [span](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9380598/1684247) or a div.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need to add a tooltip to an element, but i didn't want it to be an  tag.

I chose to use a  tag instead like this:

```
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-medicine pharmacy-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Pharmacy Tooltip"></span>
```

Which will display (when hovering on medicine glyphicon) the message: Pharmacy Tooltip

If you want to go one step further you can even style the tooltip however you want, the following code block would be how you can change styling of it:

```
.tooltip {
  filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 2px 5px);
  .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
  }
  .tooltip-arrow {
    border-right-color: white;
  }
}
```

This will change the background color of the tooltip and the arrow of the tooltip to be white with red text and a drop shadow round the tooltip.

If you're using bootstrap make sure to include the following line of code where ever the tooltip will be used:

`$('.someClass').tooltip();`

This will ensure that you're using the bootstrap tooltip and not the default built in browser tooltip